# Why do eyes feel exhausted after reading on a computer screen for a long time?

Tags: vision, human-eye

Similar question before closing this one was: [Question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19212/which-part-of-human-eyes-is-getting-tired).

The answer holds true for most of the observations, but my observation differs from what is described in that question. Even if we consider that tiring eyes is due to the constant focus which creates stress in the ocular muscles, the extent to which eyes feel tired in the case of books/physical paper is lesser than that of display appliances.

Even if I keep screen brightness comfortably low, still there is a slight stress build up, which does not happen when I read a newspaper or something similar physically?

What is the exact attribute of computer displays which causes this? We have come a long way from those CRT displays and current imaging technologies offer realistic and immersive experience. Is it the refreshing frequency, which of the display which causes this stress?

Comment: Welcome lousycoder. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. It's unclear to me if this will stay open as it's possibly just the wrong side of off-topic. I'd be interested in the answer anyhow. *Not voting to close.*

Comment: @ARogueAnt. The previously answered question has mostly answered my question. Could you please share why reading books is not tiring as watching displays even though both of them could be as near as 30-50 centimeters to the eyes.

Comment: If the nominated duplicate doesn't completely answer your question, you can [edit] and make it clear in what respect that's the case, it'll then enter the reopen review-queue.